Show that operator is self-adjoint

Show that the operator B in a space of $2 \times 2$ real matrices is self-adjoint
$$ BX = X \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

I attempted to apply the theorem that an operator is self-adjoint if and only if its matrix in some orthogonal basis is Hermitian. So, by multiplying both sides of the equation by $X^{-1}$, we obtain $$ B =  X \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix} X^{-1}. $$ In $X$ basis the matrix of operator B is Hermitian.
Am I making no sense? I’d be grateful for any assistance and tips!

Yes, you're making no sense.  First of all, what Hilbert space is $B$ an operator on?  Presumably the $2 \times 2$ complex matrices, but what's the inner product?  My guess is $\langle X, Y \rangle = \text{Tr}(X^* Y)$, but you should confirm that.  Now this is a $4$-dimensional space, so the matrix of your operator will be a $4 \times 4$ matrix: it's not going to be the same as that $2 \times 2$ matrix.

It is very unclear. Can you describe your question a bit?

No inner product given. Space is a space of $2 \times 2$ real matrices.

@RobertIsrael Why $4 \times 4$? How to multiply B on X then?

Hint: write down a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and determine the action of $B$ on this basis.

@whpowell96 And then? I'm sorry I don't get what to do next. I've got four matrices now

@GlebCloudy What do you mean by an "orthogonal basis" for the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices? If there's "no inner product given", then what would it mean for two matrices to be orthogonal to each other?

@BenGrossmann You're right; now I'm totally confused.

@GlebCloudy Check your notes or your textbook. I would bet that Robert's comment is correct and that somewhere along the line it was established that the space of matrices comes with the usual inner product.

@GlebCloudy The fact that $B$ is an operator on a 4-dimensional vector space means that the matrix associated with this linear operator has shape $4 \times 4$

@GlebCloudy Note that the way $B$ acts on $X$ in the equation
$$
B(X) = X\pmatrix{1&2\2&4}
$$
is as a function, $B$ is not being "multiplied" by $X$. Multiplying by $X^{-1}$ on both sides the way that you did makes about as much sense as the step
$$
f(x) = \sin(x) \implies f = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}
$$

@BenGrossmann There is no information provided about an inner space in the assignment. So, without information about the inner space, does the assignment have no solution?

@GlebCloudy I would suspect that the teacher who gave the assignment has previously established what the inner product was, and expected students to remember this. That's why I said that you should check your notes. But yes: if there is no information that you're expected to have access to regarding this inner product, then the assignment has not provided sufficient information.

@whpowell96 Do you mean that OP should write down a basis... that happens to be orthonormal? If not, then how does the matrix representation of $B$ relative to this basis give you any information about whether $B$ is self-adjoint?

@BenGrossmann Thanks! I'm shocked.

Ben I am aware that OP hasn't specified an inner product. Presumably OP is missing some information or unaware of an assumption about the inner product. My hint is still a necessary first step to obtaining a matrix representation of $B$ which is used to determine self-adjointness. The canonical basis is orthonormal w.r.t the standard inner product obviously.

@whpowell96 Ok, but a necessary stipulation regarding your hint is that the basis should be orthonormal, otherwise the matrix representation wouldn't help. Anyway, I'd say that the nicer approach here is to avoid finding a matrix representation at all

I agree but OP specified their definition of self-adjointness in terms of matrix representations

@whpowell96 Fair enough

@BenGrossmann To be precise: it was a test, and there was no mention of the inner product in the assignment. I'm trying to figure it out now because I couldn't complete the task. Thanks for your help, now I have a lot to think about.
